# If an $n \times n$ matrix represents a reflection, then its determinant is negative. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Why do square matrices associated with reflections have a negative determinant?

Can someone give a proof, perhaps for the $2 \times 2$ case?

Comment: What does determinant mean to you? Not the formula, but what it _means_. That should answer your question.

Comment: It represents an area, but I am not sure specifically what area.

Comment: Consider a triangle with a counterclockwise direction associated with it. That is, if the vertices are A, B, C then going counterclockwise will take us from A to B to C then back to A.  Now reflect that in a line external to the triangle, A-> A', B-> B', C-> C'.  Do you see that going from A' to B' to C' then back to A' you are going clockwise?

Comment: Reflection in what? A point, a plane, a line??

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove It represents the oriented area, a reflections reverses the orientation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many sorts of reflections. Let $U$ be an $r$-dimensional subspace of the euclidean space $X:={\mathbb R}^n$ with its standard scalar product. Then any vector $x\in X$ can be written in a unique way as $x=u+v$ with $u\in U$ and $v\in U^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of $U$. The *reflection* $R$ of $x$ in $U$ is defined by
$$x=u+v\quad \mapsto\quad  u-v\ .$$
If we choose   bases $(e_1,\ldots,e_r)$ and $(e_{r+1},\ldots, e_n)$ of $U$ and $V$ then the matrix of $R$ becomes
$$[R]={\rm diag}(\ \underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_r,\ \underbrace{-1,\ldots,-1}_{n-r}\ )\ ,$$
and its determinant is $(-1)^{n-r}$. In particular, if $R$ is a reflection in a hyperplane, i.e., if ${\dim}(U)=n-1$, then ${\rm det}(R)=-1$.